# When/how does MemoryCache do its housekeeping?

Tags: .net-4.0

When/how does System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache do its housekeeping?

Is there a background thread that clears expired items?

MSDN mentions a polling interval but doesn't say how it is triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, it runs a `System.Threading.Timer`.

Look at the `MemoryCacheStatistics` class via Reflector .NET.